# Rscript unexpected numeric constant in csv

Tags: r

I am trying to read in data from a tab delimited file using an R script that I am calling with the Rscript command. Within the script, the call is as follows:

```
# within R script called via Rscript
df <- read.csv(file="sig_ids_MCF7_6.mat", header=F, sep="\t")
# produces the error "Error: unexpected numeric constant in "CPD001_MCF7_6H:BRD-A02759312-003-17-9   0.357200026512"
# Execution halted
```

But when I simply read this file using the R console, everything works fine.

```
# within R console
df <- read.csv(file="sig_ids_MCF7_6.mat", header=F, sep="\t")
```

This file is quite large, but an excerpt is below:

```
$ head -n 3 sig_ids_MCF7_6.mat | cut -f 1-6
CPD001_MCF7_6H:BRD-A02759312-003-17-9   0.357200026512  -1.81755006313  1.26394999027   0.998450040817  0.267199993134
CPC020_MCF7_6H:BRD-A23290232-001-02-3   0.371100068092  0.52954274416   0.0509457141161 0.202583178878  0.667555570602
CPC016_MCF7_6H:BRD-K98521173-001-03-8   -0.513105690479 -0.618193089962 -0.177318453789 0.425470650196  0.0688976272941
```

I'm running 64 bit R version 2.15.1 on Mac OS X Version 10.7.5. Any idea why this might be happening? I've been googling quite a bit with no luck. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Stupid mistake, I had my command arguments in the wrong order and Rscript was trying to run the data file as a script. My apologies.